# Why does the "Arduino" tag have such low quality questions and how can we fix this?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [arduino](/questions/tagged/arduino) isn't that well maintained. I don't have enough reputation as of now to clean up the tag, but it seems pretty... *crummy* for a few reasons:

- **There are many off topic or vague questions that *just aren't closed.*** There are some duplicates, some vague questions, and even some *electronic based* questions here. This may be because of the lag in the close vote queue. I've flagged a few extreme cases.
- **They aren't getting edited at all.** (i.e. 90% of them have *i need help with this. it doesnt work* or similar within the body.
- **Not all are answered.** It's a 85% answer rate; that's still high but it shouldn't be that low. Betas "need" around 90% typically. This can't really be fixed, but I'd imagine with higher quality questions a little more answers might trickle in.

I *could* help some of this, but the queues are already flooded: no need to add 500 new flags in the close vote queue over a two week period. Also, I don't want to have to edit 1K answers or questions to clean it up. To clean it up would require a group of people with higher reputation working together. **Do we need to fix this? If so, how could we do a large task such as this efficiently?**

Comment: You're complaining about *that*? Why don't you take a look at [[tag:php]] or [[tag:android]]...

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, the Q to A ratio isn't very good at all for those, however, it *does* seem like the tag is filled with a bunch of questions to be closed.

Comment: On a recent one he asks "i know the coffee maker must be right next to the computer" - Sir, please reconsider. They are programming coffee pots - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694932/arduino-tweet-a-pot-with-wifi-shield

Comment: Wonder if this would improve if Arduino.SE gets out of beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino

Comment: @Brad Ironically, I'm a mod on that beta. :-) Anyway, I think there will be less questions here with Arduino. However, that doesn't mean the quality will improve. Part of the problem is the close vote queue... if that was less full I would flag more things there. (Although, only me wouldn't make that much of a difference.)